# What happens to %rax after "movq %rax, (%rdi)" executed?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

What I am curious about is the remaining values in %rax after executing the code.
For instance, let %rax is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
And I executed the code.
Then is 0xFF...FF still in %rax?

And my final question is the one below.
In an assembly code which is
decode1:
movq %rax, (%rdi)
ret

Why is return command not included in the original c code of function decode1?
I learned the value of %rax is returned when 'ret' executed.

Comment: I missed some assembly codes in the decode1:, but assume that %rdi is pointer, there was a value in %rax before the line "movq ..."

Comment: `mov` is write-only.  The new contents of the register don't depend on the old, either architecturally or micro-architecturally for 32 or 64-bit operand-size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov` actually means copy; the source operand is unaffected. So, after `movq %rax, (%rdi)` `rax` still contains whatever it contained before.

> Why is return command not included in the original c code of function decode1?
>   I learned the value of %rax is returned when 'ret' executed.

There's no concept of "returning something" in x86 assembly; `ret` just returns the execution to the caller. The bit you say about `rax` is actually that in virtually all x86_64 calling conventions integer or pointer return values are put there before returning, so the caller expects the return value to be there. If this is a `void` function, `rax` has no particular significance - it's just a clobbered register as any.